# C# Problem with Running Console Command

Tags: c#, console

Hi i'm trying to run a dos command in c#. When I run the command from console it works fine. But I can't get the output of the command. Code is below.

```
String runCommand = "-classpath C:\\Users\\ZZZ\\Desktop\\javatest Javatest >C:\\outt.txt";
ProcessStartInfo runProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java.exe", runCommand);
runProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
runProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
runProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process runProcess = new Process();
runProcess.StartInfo = runProcessStartInfo;
runProcess.Start();

StreamReader output = runProcess.StandardOutput;  
OutputTextBox.Text = output.ReadToEnd();

runProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Also when i set the runCommand to sth like "dir" it works fine. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call to cmd /c

You can call to java directly.

```
ProcessStartInfo runProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
              "java.exe", "-classpath C:\\Users\\ZZZ\\Desktop\\javatest Javatest")
runProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
runProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
runProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process runProcess = new Process();
runProcess.StartInfo = runProcessStartInfo;
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
runProcess.WaitForExit();
runProcess.Close();


OutputTextBox.Text = output;
```

Comment: Thank you, you are right about cmd, but it still doesn't work. :z

Comment: Are you sure your Java application writes anything to standard output? (i.e. does it write anything when you redirect output from CMD with "> myfile.txt")

Comment: when i run it on shell it writes(also when i redirect) the output. But it doesn't even create myfile.txt when I run it from the code.

Comment: Have you verified that your Java program actually runs? I.e. there are no exceptions thrown when you call process.Start?

Comment: yes the java program runs from console when i run it with the following commands
java -classpath C:\Users\ZZZ\Desktop\javatest Javatest
java -classpath C:\Users\ZZZ\Desktop\javatest Javatest >C:\output.txt

And the code block is in try block, no exception is caught. The problem is it does not create a file called output.txt when it is run from c# code. Even if there is no output it should create an empty file right?

Comment: Wait; do you want to write to a file, or direct the output to the box? Does your Java program write to a file *and* the screen?

Comment: Sorry, I see I have written ambiguously. My Java program writes to screen. I tried redirecting it to see if it works that way. When I redirected I tried the following code part and it didn't create the file outt.txt.                           String runCommand = "-classpath C:\\Users\\ZZZ\\Desktop\\javatest Javatest >C:\\outt.txt"
In either case, it doesn't work. Sorry for confusion

Comment: Does your program require any input? When you run it normally, do you have to type 'enter' to exit, or anything like that?

Comment: No, actually it is a simple hello world program. It is only this.

class Javatest {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  System.out.println("hello world");
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make sure you wait for the program to exit, as well. You can do something like this:

```
runProcess.Start();

using (StreamReader output = runProcess.StandardOutput)
{
    OutputTextBox.text = output.ReadToEnd();
}

runProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Of course, you will have to make sure that your java program is writing to standard output in the first place, and that it doesn't require any user input in order to finish running.

Comment: thank you, i edited it. the java program writes to std output when I run it from console or when i redirect the output to a file. it just does't work in c# code

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the StandardError stream. Sometimes Java puts the output text in the error stream.

```
String runCommand = "-classpath C:\\Users\\ZZZ\\Desktop\\javatest Javatest >C:\\outt.txt";
ProcessStartInfo runProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java.exe", runCommand);
runProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
runProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
runProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process runProcess = new Process();
runProcess.StartInfo = runProcessStartInfo;
runProcess.Start();

StreamReader output = runProcess.StandardError;  
OutputTextBox.Text = output.ReadToEnd();

runProcess.WaitForExit();
```